# Need alternative to CancellationToken

Tags: c#, azure

I want to cancel a Task that downloads a file. My research says that this should be doable with the use of a CancellationToken. I've followed the guidelines explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674886.aspx) and made everything work up until I needed to change this line of code:

```
await cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(writeStream);
```

To be like this line:

```
await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(writeStream, cancellationToken);
```

The later method fails because I do not have the most recent version of WindowsAzure. While the most recent version supports that second method (as seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadtostreamasync.aspx)) I simply do not have access to that method, and upgrading to the most recent version is NOT an option.

Is there another way to cancel a Task with that line of code, or am I forced to drop this feature?

Edit: I am using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll v6.0.0.0

Comment: Please tell us what version of Storage Client library (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll) are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there another way to cancel a Task with that line of code, or am I forced to drop this feature?

You can't easily cancel uncancelable code. This is true regardless of language, platform, OS, or whether the code is asynchronous/synchronous.

If the code doesn't natively support cancellation (as in your case), then you have a few options.

One is to not cancel the *operation* (download); rather, just cancel the *wait*. This gives you the advantage that you can *pretend* to cancel the operation, but be aware that the operation will continue executing as though nothing happened.

Another option is to use a sneaky little trick that works for most Windows operations: close an underlying handle. This in turn usually causes the operation to fail. In this case, there isn't anything you can close related to the blob, but you can try closing the stream it's writing to.

If the operation is synchronous, you can step it up a notch by running the operation in a separate thread, and then aborting that thread on cancel. I do not recommend this approach, since aborting threads is very bad for your application's long-term health. However, this is the approach used by ASP.NET, which will also occasionally recycle your application just to fix these long-term health issues.

Finally, if you need a reliable way to truly cancel an operation without the dangers of aborting threads, there is the nuclear option: put the operation in a separate process. Killing a *process* is clean (unlike aborting threads), and it will actually force the operation to cancel. I have only had to do this once; it wasn't pretty, but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can always cancel a task that doesn't support cancellation in API in couple of ways. The one I usually opt for is here. Note any side effects.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx

Other way is you use Task.Run with cancellation logic in it.

Comment: To quote that source: "Requesting that the async operation itself cancel... is enabled by passing a CancellationToken to the async operation in question." Which seems to rely on my missing method.